# Data isn't transmitted between QTcpSockets and Java Sockets

Tags: java, c++, qt, sockets, tcp

So I have two applications, one is written in C++ using Qt5 and the other one is written in Java. The C++ application acts as a client that connects to a `ServerSocket` object in the java application which then instantiates a socket from the connection. When I then try to send a string to the server, I either have to send the string repetitively (like 20000 times) or the server doesn't receive anything at all.

```cpp
QString s = " This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection\n";
QTcpSocket *sock = new QTcpSocket;
sock->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 5000, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
sock->waitForConnected(5000);
QTextStream out(sock);
while(!sock->waitForBytesWritten(3000)) {
        out << s << endl;
}
```

Where the code above would not yield any results, the following yields segmented strings as well as duplicate received strings for the server:

```cpp
QString s = " This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection\n";
QTcpSocket *sock = new QTcpSocket;
sock->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 5000, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
sock->waitForConnected(5000);
QTextStream out(sock);
do {
        out << s << endl;
} while(!sock->waitForBytesWritten(3000) | 1);
```

The server is a simple java program like this:

```java
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5000);
Socket s = ss.accept();
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
while (true){
        String tmp = in.readUTF();
        System.out.println(tmp);
        if (tmp.contains(" ")){
              break;
}
```

I would expect the output to be a simple `This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection`; however, the result is either nothing or something along these lines:

```
his is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection

 This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection
```

Do you have any idea as to how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know "Q" but if I was writing the client in Java I'd have to send a "flush" after the call to `out` to get it to actually send the packet.

Comment: Flushing made no difference

Comment: Flushing would push the message out of the stream's buffer and into the network stack, but TCP offers no guarantees that the network stack won't buffer it or split it across multiple TCP packets. If you want to send discrete messages in a TCP stream, you need to wrap the messages in a protocol.

Comment: Do you have an idea as to how I would do that in Qt?

Comment: If flushing makes no difference, then I think your protocol stack is broken.  Better go ask the QT folks how their stuff works.  While a "flush" isn't guaranteed, a protocol stack should make a best effort to send the data out on the wire, and realistically that should always succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to read the data into a `byte[]` and then convert using a the string constructor to a string as such:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5000);

Socket s = ss.accept();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

byte[] b = new byte[1024];
in.read(b);

String tmp = new String(b, "UTF8");
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(tmp);
```

I have no idea why, but it is the solution I arrived at. The client almost stayed the same although minor changes were made:

```
QString s = "This is a test string that will be sent to the server upon connection\n";

QTcpSocket *sock = new QTcpSocket;

sock->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 5000, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

sock->waitForConnected(5000);


do {
        sock->write(s.toUtf8());
        sock->flush();

        sock->waitForBytesWritten();
} while (sock->isValid() && sock->bytesToWrite() > 0);
```

Comment: See my note (5) to understand why your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

(1) `waitForBytesWritten` may fail on Windows - better use the signal `bytesWritten()`

(2) The loop

```
while(!sock->waitForBytesWritten(3000) | 1);
```

looks like an endless loop to me independent of the return code from waitForBytesWritten

(3) What is the idea of `waitForBytesWritten` in the context of your program? It may return after the first byte written to the stream!

(4) What's the idea of

```
if (tmp.contains(" ")){
              break;
```

To me, this looks like it might break after any blank received - e.g. the first blank after "This". It might as well break after several lines, depending on how much readUTF delivers (I'm not an expert in Java).

(5) `readUTF` expects Strings in modified UTF8 format, but Qt will not send Strings in modified UTF8 (with a leading 16 bit Integer containing the length). Thus Java will interpret the first two characters ('Th') as length and then the lottery may start - depending on these two characters, the decoding will return seemingly arbitrary results.

Comment: So you are saying that if I were to prepend the length of the string to a byte array containing the length that would solve it you think?

Comment: Depending on your strings, readUTF might deliver unexpected results, e.g. the coding of nul and supplementary characters is different in Qt.

Comment: But isn't the characterset of UTF standard so by using the QString method `toUtf8()` that should be avoided no?

Comment: UTF is standardized, but readUTF doesn't read standardized UTF8 but instead "modified UTF8". Just google the term or read the interface description of Java here!